# SpringBoot JPA Many2One, One2Many not work properly in two way

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have created a program by using JPA and SpringBoot, the database is Postgresql, i have two entities: Parent and Child:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();
}
```

And the Child entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent")
  private Parent parent;
}
```

Then in the Application, i have autowired two repositories to do some tests:
**It works when i do:**

```
Child child1 = new Child("Lucas", new Date(2012, 12,12));
Parent parent1 = new Parent("Jack", "Bauer");
child1.setParent(parent1);
childRepository.save(child1);
```

**In the table Child, the parent id is set correctly.**

**But if i create from another side, it doesn't work:**

```
Child child1 = new Child("Lucas", new Date(2012, 12,12));
Parent parent1 = new Parent("Jack", "Bauer");
childRepository.save(child1);
parent1.getChildren().add(child1);
parentRepository.save(parent1);
```

**No error appears, and no relationship is updated in the table Child**

Can you tell me why?

Thank you.

Comment: There seems to be a problem in this line: parentRepository.save(account1); You are saving "account1", this should probably be parent1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, BUT it doesn't work with parent1

Answer (score 2):

1. **Bidirectional @OneToMany:**

The best way to map a `@OneToMany` association is to rely on the `@ManyToOne` side to propagate all entity state changes:

***Parent Class:***

```
@OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "post", 
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<Child> childs = new ArrayList<>();

//Constructors, getters and setters removed for brevity

    public void addChild(Child child) {
        childs.add(child);
        comment.setChild(this);
    }

    public void removeChild(Child child) {
        childs.remove(child);
        child.setPost(null);
    }
```

***Child Class:***

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;
```

The @ManyToOne association uses FetchType.LAZY because, otherwise, we’d fall back to EAGER fetching which is bad for performance

The parent entity, features two utility methods (e.g. addChild and removeChild) which are used to synchronize both sides of the bidirectional association. You should always provide these methods whenever you are working with a bidirectional association as, otherwise, you risk very subtle state propagation issues.

**For test :**

```
Parent parent1=new Parent();
// set datas into parent1 and to put childs we can use the utility method addChild
parent1.addChild(new Child(datas...))
parent1.addChild(new Child(datas...)) //etc
parentRepository.save(parent1);
```

Answer (score 2):

The question you have is why does the `Cascade` operation fail to work when you add a `Child` to the `Parent` and have a cascade annotation on the `Parent`.

Generally the owner of the relationship, in this case the `Child` as indicated by the `mappedBy="parent"` annotation, is responsible for persisting the relation. You have demonstrated this with the unidirectional mapping for the `Child` -- done with the `ManyToOne` annotation.

```
Child child = new Child();
Parent parent = new Parent();
child.setParent(parent);
parentRepo.save(parent);
childRepo.save(child);
```

You then you tried the same thing with the bidirectional mapping in the `Parent` -- done with the `OneToMany` annotation. Since this annotation includes the `mappedBy="parent"` annotation it is not the owner and normally anything added to the `Set<Child> children` would be ignored. However you added the `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` annotation so this overrides the ownership settings and allows the `Parent` entity to persist relations for a subset of operations and specific conditions as determined by the `CascadeType` value.

But how is the parent to know which children to persist? I assume that it looks at whether the child instance has already been persisted. If it has, then no cascade operation would be needed. When you persisted the child instance yourself you circumvented the cascade operation.

```
Child child = new Child();
Parent parent = new Parent();
Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();
childRepo.save(child);
children.add(child);
parent.setChildren(children);
parentRepo.save(parent);
```

This particular code give me an error because the child instance has been saved and detached and then asked to be saved again. The error condition doesn't always happen - I think depending on whether the parent is new or has been retrieved from the db.

> org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:

So if you want the `Parent` entity to do a cascade you have to pass it a `Child` instance that has not been already saved. Note that you still have to set the child's parent in order for the relation to be created otherwise the parent will persist a parentless child.

```
Child child = new Child();
Parent parent = new Parent();
child.setParent(parent);
Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();
children.add(child);
parent.setChildren(children);
parentRepo.saveAndFlush(parent);
```

And this works fine for me. Note that I create the `Set` of children myself instead of creating it every time a `Parent` entity is instantiated. Generally you will be doing queries against a database much more often then updates and for every query the JPA provider will put its own `Collection` class into the `children` property of the `Parent` and so the set you instantiated will generally end up on the garbage heap -- somewhat inefficient.

```
@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;

@Entity
public class Parent  {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<Child> children;
```